# Attrs, Styles, Themes not picked up under Oreo

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-8.0-oreo

Under Oreo my Theming stopped working (works on lower level API) and is not picked up. I have the following:

report_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/company_list_header"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?companyTextTitle">
```

attrs.xml

```
<attr name="companyTextTitle" format="reference"/>
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Black" parent="Theme">
    <item name="companyTextTitle">@style/company_text_title</item>
</style> 

<style name="Theme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:listViewStyle">@style/list</item>
    <item name="android:absListViewStyle">@style/list</item>
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/edittext</item>   
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/stdbutton</item>        
    <item name="android:spinnerStyle">@style/spinner</item>   
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/spinneritem</item>   
    <item name="android:checkboxStyle">@style/checkbox</item>   
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radio</item>    
    <item name="android:preferenceStyle">@style/preference</item>    
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/btn_radio</item>         
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/spinnerradio</item>    
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/stdbutton</item>                               
</style>
```

styles.xml:

```
<style name="company_text_title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|left</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#004488</item>
</style>
```

In my Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.report_layout);
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Black);
```

Manifest:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/> 

    <activity android:name=".ReportList" android:label="@string/app">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xyz.app.REPORTLIST"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 14
}
```

Does not like:

```
style="?companyTextTitle">
```

but this works:

```
style="@style/company_text_title">
```

Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, one have to set:

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Black);
```

before:

```
setContentView(R.layout.report_list);
```

I.e.

```
setTheme(R.style.Theme_Black);
setContentView(R.layout.report_layout);
```

Having said that it used to also work the other way around before Oreo...